# How to clear/reset a row filter Apex

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I have a Interactive Report that I would like to reset the row filter, programmatically.

[Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKqD8.png)

I would like to know if this is possible, either dynamicly or by other means.

apex.region("IR").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("reset-report");

and

apex.region("IR").call("getActions").invoke('reset-report');

But these are both referencing a report and this is a row filter?

I was able to do it coming from another linked page with the following.
[link reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI7xM.png)

But I think it would be better done via a page load to cover all other pages that arn't linked?

Tried this before header with no luck:

[Pre-Rendering Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EanXd.png)

[Process settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a40p.png)

Found a new issue releated to clicking the next arrow button on the pagination, this does reset the filter. It would be only necessary to reset the filter if we leave the current page_id.  Example we are on page_id 4 and we are hitting the next button to see all of the data in the IR with the current filter,only if we leave page_id 4 is when we need to reset the filter.

[image: next arrow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Interactive Report (IR) region and and Interactive Grid (IG) region are 2 components with a very different architecture. The IR is a lot "older" (introduced in APEX 3.2), is more "server-based" and does not have a client model (and the corresponding javascript programming options) that the IG has. The IG javascript calls you are showing in your question will never work for an IR because it doesn't have any client architecture listening for those actions.

Originally, the only way to reset a filter on a page is by doing so through the URL.
However, in APEX 5 the API `APEX_IR` was added so the report filters can be cleared or reset on page load in a page process: for example:

```
DECLARE
  l_region_id apex_application_page_regions.region_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT region_id 
    INTO l_region_id
    FROM apex_application_page_regions 
   WHERE application_id = :APP_ID and page_id = :APP_PAGE_ID and static_id = 'emp';
    APEX_IR.CLEAR_REPORT(
        p_page_id   => :APP_PAGE_ID,
        p_region_id => l_region_id,
        p_report_id => NULL);
 END;
```

The code above needs to go in page process and the assumption is that the IR has a static id of emp

Comment: I tried your option and it doesn't work for the IR,  I added this in the "Execute when Page Loads".  And the row filter is still in place?

Comment: This is pl/sql code. It should go in a before header page process. The "Execute when Page Loads" is for javascript code only. Does this make sense ?

Comment: No I don't understand where to add this code, I assumed it would be a Pre-Rendering before header?  But that didn't work.  I'll add some more screenshots to what I have tried,

Comment: Listire  I figured it out, I forgot to define the static id, for the IR.

Comment: Good point I added that in the answer.

Comment: One thing I did notice today was the filter is resetting when I select the pagaination next arrow, to get to the next 10 records of the IR?  Is there anyway to only reset the column filter when we move away from the current page id ?  I can try to post some screenshots to make it clear.

Comment: Hmm... no your page doesn't know where it is invoked from. You could add a page item P1_RESET_FILTER (or a request) with a value and use that as a serverside condition on the page process but you'd have to specify that everywhere the page is linked from

Comment: Another solution is to have a “reset” button on the page so the user can decide to clear the filters.